# php : SEO friendly urls

Tags: php, url, .htaccess, seo

I am working on a new project, I want to create SEO friendly URL's for this site like

mysite.com/first_content, mysite.com/second_content. URL's must be dynamic which means URL's must related to the content title. How can I done this ? Is is possible to use htacess, ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sample rules for .htaccess (once you make sure mod_rewrite is enabled):

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

These rules match any URL that isn't an already existing file and passes it to your script.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do that by using `.htaccess` for that. There are plenty of tutorials available on Internet.

The module used to do that is called `mod_rewrite`. It re-routes incoming requests based on regular expression patterns.

**These tutorials explains it pretty well:**
1. [A Beginner's Guide to URL Rewriting](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting)
2. http://www.easymodrewrite.com/guide-syntax

You will also need to know the basics about regular expressions if you plan to use mod_rewrite. This site is one of the best regular expression resources out there.
- [Regular Expression Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

In .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)$ index.php?name=$2
</IfModule>
```

Where $2 has the content of the second parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On  
  RewriteRule ^.* index.php
</IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```