# How do I create permalinks that are database driven?

Tags: php, mysql, database, permalinks

I'm looking for a way to translate

http://www.mysite.com/articles.php?id=1

into

http://www.mysite.com/articles/name_of_article_from_field_in_database_with_id_1

I'm ok with doing some sort of RewriteRule with Mod Rewrite, but I'm not sure how to do it exactly.  My pages are coded in PHP pulling from a MySQL database.

Hopefully someone can tell me how to do this!

I know there are others looking for a similar answer.

Thanks again!

NCoder

Comment: Duplicate of [php : SEO friendly urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615097/php-seo-friendly-urls) and many many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need a rewrite rule in your web server configuration to translate e.g. `/123` to `/index.php?id=123` - it's not a PHP issue per se.

Comment: I've heard of rewrites a little bit but have never done them.  What's the best way to do this so that what it rewrites to is pulled from an additional field in my database?  Thanks!

Comment: yitznewton is right. Here's a good tutorial on how to do it with .htaccess files: http://zenverse.net/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess/

Comment: @NCoder: Do you mean a slug: where `http://example.org/some-article` will translate to `/index.php?slug=some-article`, and then your app will look for "some-article" in the db? If so, you would need to add a slug column to your table (let's say `article.slug`), and create the slug when a new article is submitted. Then, for retrieval, you query `article.slug` for the supplied value.

Comment: Well I'm not sure exactly what I need.  I have a page http://example.org/index.php?id=1 that would pull a news record from my database, then http://example.org/index.php?id=2 which pulls a different news article.  I'm just looking for something that's better SEO and looks wise.  So your wisdom/advice is appreciated!

Comment: @NCoder: do you have an example of what kind of URL you are looking for? My example strikes me as the most basic/common. If you do not, and are looking for SEO advice, you should reframe the question - it's not a programming question at all.

Comment: I did some research and read through your comments.  Basically I need http://mysite.com/articles.php?id=1 to translate into http://mysite.com/name_of_article_field_with_id_1_in_database.  I'm ok with doing some sort of RewriteRule with Mod Rewrite, but how do I get this affect?  My pages are coded in PHP if that makes a difference.  Thanks!

Comment: @NCoder: it really sounds like it's the scenario in my comment of Feb 16 15:20 -- user requests `http://example.org/some-articles-title`, the rewrite rule sends the request to your handler (e.g. index.php), which does a query on the database like `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE slug='some-articles-title'` (obviously after sanitizing the title)

Comment: @yitznewton YEAH!  That's what I'm looking for, can you provide a little more detailed of how I do this? Thanks!

Comment: @NCoder: Well, IMO because that's such a fundamental paradigm in PHP/*SQL web apps, your best bet is to look for a tutorial or book on this sort of thing. I don't think SO users are going to recreate that in response to your question. Also, you can delegate some of the nitty gritty by using a framework like symfony or CakePHP; although I think it's worth it to create a site from scratch, so you get the feel of what is going on under the hood of the framework.

Comment: @yitznewton I get that it's fundamental, but the reason I posted on here was because I couldn't find a tutorial that fit the slug approach you mentioned above.  If you can point me to one that would be great.

Comment: @yitznetwon to clarify, I know how to do a query from the database using PHP without any issues.  I'm just trying to understand what the rewrite looks like.  And how the handler works.  Thanks

Comment: @NCoder in httpd.conf: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]` then http://pastebin.com/mdLr5td2

Answer (score 0):

All the below stuff can be implemented with apache rewrites. You can find a ton of tutorials and documentation on how to do this.

In order to make permalinks look nice and SEO friendly, you can follow the pattern example.com/article/how-to-do-stuff as a link for the article entitled "How to do stuff". However if your site will get many articles, things will slow down a little bit because of text search in the database (that will be a hard to achieve level, but let's talk hypothetical).

As a result I'd recommend using the phpBB pattern example.com/article/12345-how-to-do-stuff where 12345 is the id of the pattern in the database (or any other id that's fast enough to select from db). That's not all. There 'should' be one more verification step, where the text from the URL, is compared with the title of selected article, and an eventual redirect to the correct URL will be done.