# How do I setup permalinks that are DB driven

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am currently using rewrite rules in `.htaccess`.

For example:

```
RewriteRule camp/johndoe /camp/2020/SuperLanding.html?c=summer2020&d=2&i=149  
RewriteRule camp/janedoe /camp/2020/SuperLanding.html?c=summer2020&d=2&i=150
```

But I have a lot of them and every time I add another person I have to make a change to `.htaccess`.

My setup is a website using HTML pages driven with PHP and MySQL.
How can I use a table in my MySql DB to drive these pretty permalinks automatically?

I have seen this question [How do I create permalinks that are database driven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018114/how-do-i-create-permalinks-that-are-database-driven). It does not seem to answer how to use the DB.

Comment: The link you found does give you the right answer: you do this in .htaccess, not in php or mysql.You need to map the incoming nice url parameters to the get parameters passed onto php. If you search for URL rewrite dynamic parameters, then you will find lots of examples even here on SO.

Comment: @Shadow I got it! I just have to add a parameter that will match the pretty permalink and look for that in my PHP. Thank you for opening my eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work as follows:

I changed my PHP to accept both the parameter `i` for number ID and parameter `p` for pretty name.

When there is no `i` GET parameter it will look for a `p` parameter and use it to look up the ID in the DB.

In `.htaccess` I changed my rule to:
`RewriteRule ^camp/(.+)$ /camp/2020/SuperLanding.html?c=summer2020&d=2&p=$1 [NC]`

Anything coming in with text after `camp/` will be forwarded to `/camp/2020/SuperLanding.html?c=summer2020&d=2`and the text will be added to the `p` parameter