# How to implement Human Readable URLS

Tags: php

I was wondering what is the best way of learning how to get human readable urls on my sites.

My understanding of a human readable URL is this

www.example.com/news/articles/how-to-make-pancakes

rather than something like this

www.example.com/news.php?articleId=100001
where 100001 is the id of my articel in an SQL Database.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried to Google Human Readable URL's and Semantic URLs but could not find a page/tutorial that matched what I was looking for. I

Comment: Look into URL rewriting

Comment: possible duplicate of [php : SEO friendly urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615097/php-seo-friendly-urls)

Comment: Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it *should* work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into URL rewriting http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

For your example a simple .htaccess rule could make that change

```
sample URL: http://example.com/articles/10001/how-to-make-pancakes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)/(.*)$ articles.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC]
```

Comment: Can you explain the syntax for the RewriteRule?

Comment: if you can't recognise the structure from this simple example then read the documentation from the link